# How to use the new ifdown and ifup?

Tags: linux, networking, bash, fedora, fedora-20

I would like to change the MAC address on a Fedora 2o webserver, but it seams that `ifdown` and `ifup` doesn't work like they used too before systemd were introduced. This is what I would like to do

```
ifdown eth0
ifconfig eth0 hw ether 00:E0:81:5C:B4:0F
ifconfig eth0 up
```

The ethernet card is called `em1` and using dhcp.

```
# ifdown em1
usage: ifdown <device name>
```

**Question**

How do I do the equivalent of the above on the *new* `ifdown` and `ifup`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, you should not be using `ifconfig` for anything anymore. Use the `ip` command instead.

Second, the command to change the MAC address is:

```
ip link set dev ${DEVICE} address ${MACADDR}
```

Finally, the best way to do this is to make it persistent by adding it to the `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-DEVICE` file.

```
MACADDR=00:E0:81:5C:B4:0F
```

Answer (score 2):

Try to check man pages for any kind of help in the specific version of your operating system.

or

Try this:

Edit the file as shown below:

```
vi /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-em1
```

Your file look like this,edit the HWADDR value in it.

```
    UUID="e88f1292-1f87-4576-97aa-bb8b2be34bd3"
    NM_CONTROLLED="yes"
    HWADDR="D8:D3:85:AE:DD:4C"
    BOOTPROTO="static"
    DEVICE="em1"
    ONBOOT="yes"
    IPADDR=192.168.1.2
    NETMASK=255.255.255.0
    BROADCAST=192.168.1.255
    NETWORK=192.168.1.0
    GATEWAY=192.168.1.1
```

And then restart the network service.